# Sending oauth access_token via Restangular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oauth

I'm using Angular 1.2 with Restangular. I need set header access_token after user is authorized and since then this header needs to be send with every request. I tried to do it this way:

```
angular.module('controllers', [])

.controller('Login', function($scope, Restangular) {

$scope.signin = {};

$scope.submitSignin = function() {
            var signin = Restangular.all('oauth/access_token');
            oauthPost = {
                grant_type: 'password',
                client_id: 'some_id',
                client_secret : 'some_secret_code',
                username: $scope.signin.email,
                password: $scope.signin.password
            };
            signin.post(oauthPost).then(function(data) {
                Restangular.setDefaultHeaders({accept: 'application/json',access_token: "somelongstring"});
            }, function() {
                console.log("There was an error.");
            });

        };

})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working for me:

```
$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token;
```